# Copy the Field value from one Form to other Form by @formula-LOTUS NOTES

Tags: forms, formula, lotus

I want to Copy the Field value from one Form to other Form by @formula, How can it do it.
Main Form name is "A", second Form name is "B",
Form "A" Field include[ID/Name/AEmail],Form "B"Field include[ID/DateTime/Record/BEamil]

When create a new record on Form B, then the Bemail Field value=AEmail when A.ID=B.ID.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: You don't want to copy field values from one FORM to another, but from one DOCUMENT to another. It is important to understand the difference... A form defines, how to display Data, a document CONTAINS the data (and is displayed with the form that is named in the "Form"- item of the document.

But now to your question: If document A is selected, when you create document B, then you simply enable the FORM- Property "Formulas Inherit Values from selected document" on the second tab of the properties.

In the field- formulas of form B just enter the name of the Field in Form A as Formula. 
e.G.: If the field in Form A is named "AEmail" then enter `AEmail` in the Value of field "BEmail" of Form B.

Beware: this "inheritance" is only done ONCE when the document is created, there will be no relation between the two documents to update BEmail, if AEmail changes. To update the values dependantly you would need to construct something like `@GetDocField( unidOfDocA; "AEmail" )` but that would need some more knowledge of the formula language.